# How to turn off webbrowser Information Bar?

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, webbrowser-control

I am using WPF C# WebBrowser control to navigate a local html file which contains js and css file links, so when my application navigates that local file I get an unwanted security warning information bar, can anyone suggest how to turn it off using C#? I know that I can turn it off in IE settings,and can use frame, but I don't want to use frame because I want to have access to HTMLElements. any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's your file to write and you trust its contents, adding the "[mark of the web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(VS.85).aspx)" silences the security messages. Just add the following line at the top of the html file:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

Note that while the warnings are muted, security isn't compromised -- the page gets to render under IE's Internet security zone rather than get access to local resources.